# Join expression ambiguous

Tags: sql, left-join

my ddl script is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE  CPR_ENTITIES
(   
     ENTITY_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
     SYSTEM_ID NUMBER(4),
     ENTITY_TYPE_ID NUMBER(8),
     GLOBAL_UID  VARCHAR2(1000),
     SYS_OBJ_UID VARCHAR2(1000),
     ENTITY_NAME VARCHAR2(1000),
     CAGE_CODE VARCHAR2(2000),
     REVISION VARCHAR2(2000),
     ENTITY_CREATION_DATE NUMBER(20),
     ENTITY_MODIFICATION_DATE NUMBER(20),
     RELEASE_DATE NUMBER(20),
     .......................,
     ........................
      CONSTRAINT "CPR_ENTITIES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ENTITY_ID"),
     CONSTRAINT "CPR_ENTITIES_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("SYSTEM_ID") REFERENCES CPR_SOURCE_SYSTEM_METADATA("SYSTEM_ID"),
     CONSTRAINT "CPR_ENTITIES_FK2" FOREIGN KEY ("ENTITY_TYPE_ID") REFERENCES CPR_ENTITY_METADATA("ENTITY_TYPE_ID"));



CREATE TABLE CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE 
(   
     VAL_ID  NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
     ENTITY_ID NUMBER(20),
     ATT_ID NUMBER(10),
     STRING_VALUE VARCHAR2(4000),
     NUM_VALUE NUMBER(10,2),
     TIMESTAMP_VALUE TIMESTAMP,
     CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(200),
     MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(200),
     CREATED_ON NUMBER(20),
     MODIFIED_ON NUMBER(20),
     IS_DELETED VARCHAR2(1),    
     CONSTRAINT "CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("VAL_ID"),
     CONSTRAINT "CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("ENTITY_ID") REFERENCES CPR_ENTITIES("ENTITY_ID"),
     CONSTRAINT "CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_FK2" FOREIGN KEY ("ATT_ID") REFERENCES CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_METADATA("ATT_ID")
 );
```

JOIN Expression:

```
 SELECT CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID, CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.STRING_VALUE
 FROM CPR_ENTITIES
     LEFT JOIN CPR_ENTITIES
         ON CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID = CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.ENTITY_ID;
```

Error given:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE"."ENTITY_ID":
>   invalid identifier

Comment: You try to select a column from the table CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE, but that table is not included in your query...

Comment: You do not have `CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE` behind `FROM` or `JOIN`

Comment: SELECT CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID,CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.STRING_VALUE FROM CPR_ENTITIES,CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE LEFT JOIN CPR_ENTITIES ON CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID=CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.ENTITY_ID;

Comment: In Your Query, you are joining CPR_ENTITIES table with same table. You need to use like this: SELECT CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID, CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.STRING_VALUE
FROM CPR_ENTITIES
LEFT JOIN CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE
     ON CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID = CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.ENTITY_ID;

Comment: Yes the left join from above is giving me the entity ids but not the values from the STRING_VALUE Column,should the query be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
SELECT CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID, CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.STRING_VALUE
FROM CPR_ENTITIES
LEFT JOIN CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE
     ON CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID = CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.ENTITY_ID;
```

Comment: Yes the left join from above is giving me the entity ids but not the values from the STRING_VALUE Column OF CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE

Comment: @SteffiDas and are there rows in `CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE` with such `ENTITY_ID`?

Comment: yes,the entity_id in CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE is its foreign key and primary key for CPR_ENTITIES

Comment: @SteffiDas the fact that `CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.ENTITY_ID` is foreign key does not mean that the row exists in `CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE`.

Comment: Yes that i know but there is data in CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE against the entity_ids

Comment: @SteffiDas replace `left join` by `join` are those ENTITY_IDs in the result?

Comment: Replacing left join with join is showing no rows selected,yes the entity_ids are in the table

Comment: @SteffiDas if there would be some `ENTITY_ID`s in common than you  see them in the result. There must be some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID, CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.STRING_VALUE
FROM CPR_ENTITIES
     LEFT JOIN CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE
         ON CPR_ENTITIES.ENTITY_ID = CPR_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.ENTITY_ID;
```